# partitions::listParts crashes R and RStudio

Tags: r, crash, partitioning

Using listParts() from the partitions package immediately causes R and RStudio to crash, no matter the input. Below is a reproducible example and traceback with error message. I'm running R 4.2.0 GUI 1.78 High Sierra build and RStudio 2022.2.3.492 on macOS Monterey 12.2.1. The function runs fine on my coworker's PC. Any help appreciated!

```html
> library(partitions)
> myVec <- c(1:3)
> partitions::listParts(length(myVec))

 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x119c1cbfe, cause 'illegal opcode'

Traceback:
 1: as.bigz(1)
 2: .fac(sum(x))
 3: setparts(x)
 4: partitions::listParts(myVec)
```

Comment: Could it be that the number of partitions is so big that you ran out ouf memory?

Comment: @Waldi, thanks for your response. I have 16gb of ram which should be more than sufficient, and R crashes even when I try only 2 partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is going on here; the partitions package is only used to evaluate listParts(3), and this is straightforward:

> listParts(3)
> [[1]]
> [1] (1,2,3)

[[2]]
[1] (1,3)(2)

[[3]]
[1] (1,2)(3)

[[4]]
[1] (2,3)(1)

[[5]]
[1] (1)(2)(3)

> 

The error comes from as.bigz(), part of the gmp package.  I would suggest using R --vanilla, and finding a minimal example that does not use partitions and reporting it to the gmp maintainer.  Best wishes, Robin